# Get timestamp with given date vs today date doesn't same result

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

**Today is 18 Oct. 2013**

```
var tmp = new Date('2013-10-18');
    tmp = tmp.getTime();
```

<kbd>1382054400000</kbd> *(GMT: Fri, 18 Oct 2013 00:00:00 GMT)*

```
var today = new Date();
    today = today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

<kbd>1382047200000</kbd> *(GMT: Thu, 17 Oct 2013 22:00:00 GMT)*

---

`.setHours(0,0,0,0)` Doesn't for set date to the midnight (00:00:00) ?

Comment: What timezone are you running that code in? Are you +/- 2hrs from GMT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Date.setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) will set time to '00:00:00:00' in your current timezome.

`Sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance.`

If you want to work in UTC hours, use [Date.setUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) instead.

Comment: Use setUTCHours instead if you want it work in utc time, see updated.